# Answer in an other question

Tags: discussion, answers

The just posted question: [Package animate is great but could it have a better animation compression?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107382/package-animate-is-great-but-could-it-have-a-better-animation-compression)
asks a question which is (in my opinion) answered in another question with a fully different purpose.

I answered in this one: [How to use autoplay (within animate package) together with a pause at the end of every playing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73067/how-to-use-autoplay-within-animate-package-together-with-a-pause-at-the-end-of)

but as can be seen, the question in the latter is not directly related to the new one.

So in general, when a question is answered by another question which was an elaboration, should one then repost a modified version of the answer?

I couldn't find this issue addressed here on meta, searching for question brings up everything :)

A duplicate doesn't seem appropriate and duplicating content seems also too much, or?

Comment: 1.Leave a comment to the elaborate answer 2. Observe the Upvotes and OP's response 3.Turn to concise answer adapting to the OP's requirement. Incase the current Q title is much broader than previous one. Don't make it as duplicate. Just upvoted your comment.

Comment: My gut reaction would be to link to the other question and show how its solution can be applied to this problem.  It's very often an enlightening experience and teaches you how to 'think outside the box' a little.

Answer (score 4):

I would go with what Sean said: pointing the OP to another answer could help him, since most likely he will continue to have issues with the package/instruction/situation he is using/having.

Furthermore, you can point DIRECTLY to the answer of the first question by using the 'sharing' option, so you don't necessarily need to address him to the question itself, and it's left on the hands of the OP to look at the question and see what was happening (if he wants to).

I also think that what textenthusiast said is important: Don't avoid writing a message or comment stating that there is a completely elaborated answer somewhere else, and if you can include a "resumed" answer, even better.

Comment: But how does one then handle that the question is resolved, I mean, it is not very searchable to find this question/answer as it is linked?